# Uploading multiple files with $_FILES reading only first file - CodeIgniter Upload Class

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload

I have 3 input file fields in my form, and every time I submit the form it only submits the first file, and the other files are not present in the images folder.

This is how I'm doing it in my Controller:

```
public function book()
{
    $id = $this->manage_model->book();
    $images = array("1","2","3");
    $this->load->library('upload');

    foreach($images as $i){

        if(!empty($_FILES['files'.$i]['name']))
        {
            $config['file_name'] = $id . '_' . $i;
            $config['upload_path'] = './photos/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';

            $this->upload->initialize($config);
            $name = "files" . $i;
            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($name))
            {
                                    //set flashdata
                redirect('manage/add_page');
            }
            else
            {
                redirect('manage/add_page');
            }
        }

    }

}
```

and these are the names of the file input fields:

```
                            <input type="file" name="files1" />
            <input type="file" name="files2" />
            <input type="file" name="files3" />
```

I'm using multipart and post method in my form so that is also not the issue. Does anyone see anything wrong? Please let me know

Comment: What have you done in an attempt to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: well I've noticed in the documentation that $this->upload->initialize() is not available (maybe not needed anymore?) so I just loaded the upload library with the configuration settings, but same result. I also tried using the recommended name for file inputs "userfile" but that didn't work. Is it possibly a limitation on size in my php.ini file? Its currently 8mb

Comment: Also just tried with a for loop with the redirect condition removed, but that doesn't import any image at all..

Comment: Oh...it's actually to do with the redirect in the else statement (I'm assuming the one in the if statement is alright because that's an error and would be appropriate). It only goes through the loop once because its being redirected, therefore not being complete. :P I just moved that out of the foreach loop. Good stuff

Comment: Nice you found out. I was about to ask why you had to redirect an incomplete loop. The first redirect is okay, but the second is wrong. Except necessary, you could just load your view instead of redirecting. That way, you could retrieve the values of upload->data() for use/report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redirect is not allowing the foreach loop to go through more than once because it is being redirected after the first loop back to the add_page.

The foreach loop should look like this:

```
foreach($images as $i){

        if(!empty($_FILES['files'.$i]['name']))
        {
            $config['file_name'] = $id . '_' . $i;
            $config['upload_path'] = './photos/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';

            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            $name = "files" . $i;
            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($name))
            {
                redirect('manage/add_page');
            }

        }

    }

    redirect('manage/add_page');
```

I guess I just think more when I post a question on here lol...